# Using a SQL Server Agent Job to run an external application?

Tags: sql-server, jobs, agent

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to run an external application like a `*.vbs` or a `*.bat` using the SQL Server Agent Job Management?

The textbox in the job's step form is to small to save all my VBS code.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Tommy

Comment: You can use the task scheduler in the control panel to run scripts or apps at a set time and interval.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I will try it next weekend at home.